# Are the Origin and Label changes for packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease suspicious?

Tags: debian, visual-studio-code, apt, repository, microsoft

While updating the apt repository indexes on Debian 12 bookworm, I was informed that the microsoft package repository for vscode had changed it's Origin and Label as shown below.  This seems an unusual and suspicious change as if a release had been made using a different workflow/tooling.  Is there any way to check that these changes were not made by an unauthorised party with access to microsoft's internal systems?

```
    Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,533 B]  
    E: Repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'vscode stable' to 'Pulp 3'
    E: Repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'vscode stable' to ''
    N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I could not find any official announcement or comment on microsoft's help/support packages regarding this and a web search of these error output did not return any matches (on duckduckgo). Neither searching stack exchange or the similar question check returned any relevant material.

Comment: Other people are looking at this - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198658

Comment: @harrymc if you want to create an answer with a summary of what happened then I would accept it to give you a reward for this useful comment

Comment: Thanks, it's done now - I've summarized this link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange happening is the subject of bug-report
[.deb Linux repos changed Origin and Label fields, triggering update errors #198658](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198658)

User eddy-geek commented on it :

> is the reference to "Pulp 3" because of some move towards
> https://pulpproject.org/about-pulp-3/ ?
>
> anyway, answering "y" seems to work properly, yielding the most recent
> (stable) version: code/stable 1.84.2-1699528352 amd64 [upgradable
> from: 1.84.0-1698839401]

However, most people were reluctant to accept the change.

User jp438-2 commented :

> This change also means users can't update using Ubuntu's inbuilt
> updating application which just shows a generic error that says
> "Failed to download repository information" with no explanation, and
> tells you to check your internet connection.
>
> The only way to see what has happened is to use apt update in the
> terminal where you can accept the change (which is not something I am
> happy to do and I have avoided).

To add mystery to the problem, user philclifford commented :

> This seems to be intermittent: so far in the last 20 mins or so two
> apt updates have succeeded without incident (and manual inspection of
> InRelease seemed normal) but 4 have exhibited the "Pulp 3" problem.
> For completeness, my configured repo is `../vscode` not `.../code`.

Other users have also commented on the fact that this change seems
to be intermittent.

Final remarks by daviddavis :

> Thanks for the bug report. We're working to fix this issue. Updates are being tracked here:
> [microsoft/linux-package-repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/linux-package-repositories/issues/96)

Followed by :

> FYI, this should be fixed now.

As the final fix may take time to propagate, it is recommended to run
`apt clean`. The problem is now reported fixed on
`Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64`.

**Conclusion** : This seems to have been a honest mistake by the developers,
but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As @harrymc commented below the question, this was investigated and confirmed to be resolved on [the github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198658).  It specifically notes that the change may need to propogate through caches so it may need to be necessary to manually flush the vscode entries of any orgnisation's caches to allow the resolution to become visible.  It is reccomended to do an `apt clean` (sudo as needed) to ensure your local apt indexes are cleared out from the old data.

There was no announcement or advisory to take any action if you had accepted the changes so this implies it was an internal microsoft release process problem and not malicious.